# How can I represent a UML role in OWL?

Tags: uml, owl, ontology

I'm formalizing a ontology in the OWL language. Currently, the ontology is documented with the use of a subset of [OntoUML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OntoUML) (that is a UML profile).

Following is a example in UML of two class and a relation:

[image: example 1]

I have the two classes and a relation between them. The role means that in the "relation a" the instances of "Class1" are acting as a specific "role".

My question is:
How can I represent this role in OWL? 
I found some references in converting UML models to OWL (e.g: [here](https://comsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/uml2owl-crv.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224423/represent-uml-diagram-in-owl)), but didn't find anything about UML roles. Are there any standard?
Create another classes could be a good idea?

Following is a example in the "real word" to clarify my situation:

[image: example 2]

In this example, a "Person" is responsible for the a "Project" when this person is acting like a "Manager". Should I create a Manager class?

Side note: I'm using Protégé to create my OWL file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard for this, but some of us are working on one at the OMG. The specification is called Semantic Information Modeling for Federation. In it there is a concept modeling profile that we believe aligns with OntoUML. We are actively working with Dr. Guizzardi on a couple of hairy areas to be sure it aligns. Google "SIMF github" if you'd like to read a draft of the spec. We expect to submit it in December. Feedback is welcome.

To answer your specific question, association ends have not been called "roles" in a UML spec since UML 1. They are properties in UML 2, and are treated as such when converted to OWL. Both SIMF and OntoUML have a «Role» stereotype you can apply to classes. That will generate a pattern in OWL involving a property like "plays" with a range of some class representing a role. A Tableau reasoner had no clue about roles and neither does OWL. You essentially have to rely on a upper ontology for the meaning of all that. Dr. Guizzardi's Unified Foundational Ontology (UFO) is one that provides that.

The first partial reference implementation of SIMF is called the Cameo Concept Modeler. You may want to download an evaluation copy and provide us with some feedback on how well it suits your needs. Keep in mind it is a work in progress, although it is being used for real work, like the Financial Industry Business Ontology (FIBO) family of standardized ontologies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep an eye in SIMF repository and try to colaborate with feedbacks if I can.